# AlarmManager can't work on android 6.0

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am working with AlarmManager, It is not working on android os 6.0.
This is my code:

```
 private void startAlarmManager(String id) {
    userID = GlobalValue.getUserName(GuideNavigationActivity.this);
    Context context = getBaseContext();
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    gpsTrackerIntent = new Intent(context, GpsTrackerAlarmReceiver.class);
    gpsTrackerIntent.putExtra("id", id);
    gpsTrackerIntent.putExtra("userID", userID);
    gpsTrackerIntent.putExtra("idCourse", idCourse.toString());
    gpsTrackerIntent.putExtra("typeCourse", typeCourse);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, gpsTrackerIntent, 0);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+ Constant.GPS_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
    }
    else if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+ Constant.GPS_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
    } else {

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+ Constant.GPS_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Please support me. Thank so much.

Comment: share the rest of the code too, especially how you get `alarmManager`

Comment: define "Not Working"

Comment: Not working mean: it doesn't send broadcast gpsTrackerIntent with time interval is 1 second. It work fine on api < 23.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AlarmManager` will not allow you to repeat that frequently, even through manual steps (e.g., `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`), on Android 5.1+.

Moreover, using `AlarmManager` for that frequent of an event is **very** inefficient, on all versions of Android. This is one of the reasons why Android no longer supports it, as too many developers were doing inappropriate things with `AlarmManager` and wasting users' batteries as a result.

If you need to get control every second, use some in-process solution, such as `ScheduledExecutorService`. Or, since your names suggest that you are tracking the location, use the appropriate APIs to let you know when the location changes, rather than trying to get control every second.

Comment: Yes, Thank so much. I will try to use ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: Very helpful. Didn't know AlarmManager was inefficient and I had been trying to figure out some way to schedule a Service for a while now. It's hard to find this information. Even when I read the developer website it just seems rare to find useful info there. Books now-a-days are too bloated and there are too many of them, many of those available are of little help. If only coming across this helpful info wasn't a matter of luck then researching and learning would be much more comfortable.