# Alarm manager not triggering everyday

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In my project I have a requirement to schedule a task to show notification at a particular time everyday. If I set it for some time today, its triggering and all is going as expected but if the schedule time is tomorrow, its not triggering. Below is my code to set the alarm manager.

```
public void setMorningRepeatingTask(Context context, int hour, int minutes) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(Constants.ALARM_MANAGER_INTENT_MORNING_UNIQUE_ACTION);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Constants.MORNING_ALARM_UNIQUE_ID, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        if(checkIfTheTimeHasPassed(calendar.getTimeInMillis())){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
        FileLogger.writeToFile("Alarm Set", "Morning repeating Alarm Set");
    }

public static boolean checkIfTheTimeHasPassed(long timeInMillis) {
        long nowTime = new Date().getTime();
        return nowTime > timeInMillis;
    }
```

Kindly help.

Comment: `AlarmManager` cannot persist in forcestop and phone restart scenarios. Are you sure you don't fall in either categories?

Comment: What is your android version? and you can see this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742368/alarmmanager-cant-work-on-android-6-0

Comment: I am handling phone restart scenario. When I receive Boot complete (android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED) broadcast, I am rescheduling the alarms. But force stop I haven't handled. How can I handle that?

Are you sure that once alarm is set, it won't run in the background even though the app is closed?

Comment: @sonnv1368 Android version is Marshmallow.

Comment: Please read my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742368/alarmmanager-cant-work-on-android-6-0 and i used ScheduledExecutorService, it is working.

Comment: @JayakrishnanSalim Once you `set` an `AlarmManager` you basically tell the Android process to launch an event after a certain time. So, even if your app is closed or in background it should be OK. Its boot and force stop scenarios that are bothersome. You are already taking care of boot. For forcestop, I've mentioned in my Play Store listing asking people to relaunch the app (and reset it there) in case they do that and also in the app itself. I cannot think of a better way.

Comment: @Shaishav By force stop you mean going to app info and hitting the force stop button there? If yes, thats not my case. I didn't force stop the app. 

Still not getting the alarm trigger.

Comment: Is there any issue in my code?

Comment: @JayakrishnanSalim The code looks fine to me. Even though you mentioned it works for smaller durations, you can still try adding HOUR to 6+ (and eventually 24) and see if it works. You possibly might already have but, you may also want to look at restrictions from Doze mode in M https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html and see if it fits your use case.

Comment: @Shaishav I had tested it by setting the alarm to repeatedly trigger every 15 mins. I tested it whole day and it was working fine. After that I changed it to AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY and it stopped working.

As far as I know about Doze, it batches background operations. So because of Doze there is a possibility that the alarm didn't ring off exactly at the set time but it should ring off at least when I unlock the screen. 
I will try in some other phones running in Lollipop or Kitkat.

Comment: If anyone has any idea, kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to the issue I am facing. 
I used `alarmMgr.set()` method instead of `alarmMgr.setRepeating()` and when the alarm rings off I set another alarm for the next day. In this way, it will repeat day after day. :)

I still would like to know whats wrong with `alarmMgr.setRepeating()` method. So, if anyone has any idea, please post the solution.

Below is the code I implemented.

```
public void setMorningRepeatingTask(Context context, int hour, int minutes, boolean forceScheduleNextDay) {
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_ALARM_TIME, Constants.VALUE_MORNING_ALARM);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Constants.MORNING_ALARM_UNIQUE_ID, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
        if (Utility.checkIfTheTimeHasPassed(calendar.getTimeInMillis()) || forceScheduleNextDay) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
        Log.i("Morning Alarm", "Alarm is set for " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + " at "
                + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        FileLogger.writeToFile("Alarm Set", "Morning repeating Alarm Set");
        FileLogger.writeToFile("Morning Alarm", "Alarm is set for " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + " at "
                + calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    }
```

The above method is for setting the alarm.

```
if (Utility.checkIfTheTimeHasPassed(calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
   calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

public static boolean checkIfTheTimeHasPassed(long timeInMillis) {
    long nowTime = new Date().getTime();
    return nowTime > timeInMillis;
}
```

The above condition will check if the time has already passed, and if it is passed, it will schedule the alarm for the next day.

When the alarm is triggered, `onReceive()` method of the BroadcastReceiver subclass will be called.

```
@Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    FileLogger.writeToFile("Alarms rang off!!", "Alarm rang");

    //Add your logic here

    setMorningRepeatingTask(context,morningTimeCalender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), morningTimeCalender.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
}
```

In this method after doing the things I want on alarm ring, I reschedule the alarm for the next day using same method.

Comment: @jaykrishnan Salim i have same issue alaram will triger today but not reapting everyday can you please post yoye working codes

Comment: @ Jayakrishnan Salim yes sure i am just checking because my flow is little diffrent i want send auto email fix time in everyday so i am mapping .

Comment: @jaykrishnasalim sorry bro i have make my own code but your answer was helpful to me sry i forgot to vote for your